# Find the largest pair of numbers representable as integers in your C system whose greatest common divisor is 1

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

I want to find the largest pair of numbers representable as integers whose GCD is 1, and the below is my code, but it is too slow and maybe stupid. Do you have a better idea? How to implement it?

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int gcd(int u, int v)
{
    while (u > 0) {
        if (u < v) {
            int t = u;
            u = v;
            v = t;
        }
        u = u - v;
    }
    return v;
}    

int main()
{
    int u, v;
    u = v = ~(1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1));    

    while (u > 0) {
        if (gcd(u, v) == 1) {
            printf("%d %d\n", u, v);
            break;
        }
        --u;
    }
}
```

Comment: `u = v = ~(1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1));`  If you're trying to get the maximum value there, there is [`<limits.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) (for `int`, the macro is `INT_MAX`).

Comment: If an int is 32-bits on your system, you're in luck, because GCD(2147483647,2147483646)=1

Comment: Also, if your code works and you want to learn how to improve it, [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask. Remember to read the relevant help pages on how to ask good questions and such.

Comment: What is your definition for "largest pair"? Presumably the one with the greatest sum, isn't it? Your algorithm just looks for the greatest number co-prime to INT_MAX, which isn't necessarily the greatest pair (imagine you found INT_MAX and INT_MAX - 4, but greatest pair was INT_MAX - 1 and INT_MAX - 2...).

Comment: By the way: You say just "integers" - actually, all natural numbers are integers, and the number of co-prime pairs is infinite, thus there is no such largest pair (yeah, sure, I know what you actually meant, but unprecise wording is dangerous food...).

Comment: Your gcd calculation is horribly inefficient. Rather try [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).

Comment: For two numbers to both be divisible by some other number, wouldn't the difference between them need to be a multiple of that other number?  So if the difference between two numbers is 1, then 1 must be the only common factor... so you just need the largest and second largest representable integers (no need for a GCD check).

Comment: This number: 2147483646 is not prime, so it is evenly divisible by other than 1,  For instance by 2.

Comment: @user3629249 ...but the numbers don't need to be prime, they just can't have any of *the same* factors besides 1.  As long as none of the factors of one number are factors of the other (other than 1), it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- You use type `int`, but there are potentially larger integral types available that would yield a larger pair: `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`... The problem specification must be more precise.
- The expression `~(1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1))` causes undefined behavior as the intermediary value `1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1)` causes an arithmetic overflow.  Note also that a byte might have more than 8 bits on some rare systems.  Use `INT_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>` for better portability.
- You do not enumerate all pairs of values: on a 32 bit system, you will find the largest pair of `int`, but for another system where `INT_MAX` is different from 2147483647, you might miss the pair with the largest sum.
- You `gcd()` function, the original Euclidean method, is very inefficient.  You should use a modulo based version such as this:

  ```
  int gcd(int a, int b) {
      while (b != 0) {
          int t = b;
          b = a % b;
          a = t;
      }
      return a;
  }
  ```
- Finally, it is obvious that for any integer `n` greater than `0`, `gcd(n, n + 1) == gcd(n, 1) == 1`.  Therefore, your problem is trivial and the solution is the largest integer and its predecessor.

  Hence the largest portable pair is this:

  ```
  #include <limits.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) {
      printf("%llu %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX - 1);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice and logical.

Comment: @kameiha: does this answer address your question?